# search values from column to other column

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in table1 ( city, studentname, id) and one column (id) on table2 . I wanted to run search against a column of id in table2 to column of id in table1 and if the first 3 digits matches then i need to take the id values of table2. How to do it in a best way.  for each city and studentname, id exists.

Table1:

| city | studentname | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| atr | vide | 12345 |
| atlm | gauda | 56789 |
| lima | gaudar | 87645 |
| limaant | gaudarie | 834567 |

Table2:

| stid |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 56789 |
| 45786 |

Output:

| city | studentname | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| atr | vide | 123456 |
| atlm | gauda | 56789 |
| limaant | gaudarie | 834567 |

I have used the following select query but i am getting syntax error near LEFT

```
SELECT 
    p1.city, p2.stutdentname 
FROM
    (SELECT id 
     FROM table2 
     CROSS JOIN table2 ON LEFT(t2.stid, LEAST(length(t2.stid), length(t1.id)) = LEFT(t2.stid, LEAST(length(t2.stid), length(t1.id)))) table t1 
WHERE 
   .....
```

Comment: LEFT is no standard ANSI SQL function. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: stid/Id columns data type?

Comment: cross join has no ON clause you need an inner join

Comment: atleast for the second table column of id the datatype is TEXT. not sure about the table1.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  city
       ,studentname
       ,stid
from    t join t2 on left(t.id,3) = left(t2.stid, 3)
```

| city | studentname | stid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| atr | vide | 123456 |
| atlm | gauda | 56789 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D_gMuKiD)

Comment: this give me only one single output, one row but I have around 200 cities and different 200  and 200 ids.

Comment: is it also possible to compare another column with the same table for ex:  t join t2 on left(t.id,3) = left(t2.stid, 3) or left(t.column2,3) = left(t2.stid, 3)

Comment: you can do that.

Comment: Hi I wanted to combine the same select query with different outputs how can I do it

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by different outputs. Post a new question with sample data and desired result and I'll take a look